# Web view unable to show webpage

Tags: android

```
public class MyPlayer extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(akki.player.R.layout.main);



    boolean flashInstalled = false;
    try {
      PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
      ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
      if (ai != null)
        flashInstalled = true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      flashInstalled = false;
    }
    if(flashInstalled){
    WebView browser=(WebView) findViewById(akki.player.R.id.webView1); 
    //
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    ;
    browser.getSettings().getPluginsEnabled();
    browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

    browser.loadUrl("http://sound30.mp3pk.com/indian/dabangg2/[Songs.PK]%2004%20-%20Saanson%20Ne%20-%20Dabangg%202.mp3");
           Toast.makeText(this, "Flash Player installed ....", 1).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Install Flash Player First  ..", 1).show();
    }
    }
```

this is my code to play a song from website. but it says webpage not available.

what is the possible error.?
thanx in advance.
i have a player.html file linking a player to the website as well.
the code is working fine as it asks to install flash player as mentioned in the code but when i launch the application it just not displays the webpage. Instead it says webpage not available.

Comment: did you set the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Its a mp3 file ,You need to download that or stream that before playing. You can use media player for playing or downloadmanager for downloading.

Comment: @StefanBe ya i have set the permission.

Comment: @rahulkapoor can u pls direct me to any link with example code for such an app.?

Comment: than u all for replying soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should download it and play it with Mediaplayer. I see that you try to use Flash player, but Flash player isnt unsupported:

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/06/no-flash-for-android-4-1-no-new-installs-after-august-15/

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that you putting mp3 file  in webview. You can change your link to http://www.musikmaza.com/2012/11/dabangg-2-2012-latest-hindi-mp3-songs.html . After changing link check that page is showing or not.

Either if you want to play mp3 files then you need a downloadManager for downloading mp3 file and then MediaPlayer for playing that file.